# How to migrate database to Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, database-migration

I'm following Codemy.com's tutorial on how to deploy a flask app with databases and I'm stuck on the final step. I'm trying to migrate my database over to Heroku but it's not working the same as for him.

He runs the python shell in Heroku and types "from app import db", then types "db.create_all()" and it works.

First off, when I type "from app import db", nothing happens. No warnings or code running or anything like that. Second, when I type "db.create_all()" I get this error message:

> RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

I don't really understand how all this works since this is my first time deploying a website. Is there anything I can do to make this work?

I'm working in Flask and I'm using SQLAlchemy for my db.

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)
```

If there was an issue in the code I can't find out since Codemy.com doesn't link his code anywhere.
Do I need to use some flask plugin like flask migrate or something? I'm really at a loss for how to make it work.